# XSL 1.0 date:difference EXSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I have struggled with finding (and using) the difference between two dates.

XSL 2.0 is not an option, but I have found EXSLT date:difference
http://exslt.org/date/functions/difference/ that might solve my problem comparing dates in XSL 1.0 - but, I haven't found any good examples on how to use it.

I have an XML-file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="gall.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>Individual Item Display</title>
<dateCreated>2016-05-23T14:26:33</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>yyyy/mm/dd</dateFormat>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>100904</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1982</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Linderholm, Helmer, 1916-1982</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">Tre ogärningskvinnor / Helmer Linderholm</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>HC</callNumber>
<item>
<totalCharges>0</totalCharges>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<dateLastUsed>2014-06-17</dateLastUsed>
<itemID>30580000599535</itemID>
<library>VALLA</library>
<location>SKÖNLITT</location>
<type>HEMLAN</type>
<dateCreated>1996-06-20</dateCreated>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>100955</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1983</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Linderholm, Helmer, 1916-82</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Fredens hemliga stig / Helmer Linderholm</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>H,U</callNumber>
<item>
<totalCharges>2</totalCharges>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<dateLastUsed>2006-12-18</dateLastUsed>
<itemID>30580001728125</itemID>
<library>VALLA</library>
<location>ULITT</location>
<type>HEMLAN</type>
<dateCreated>1996-06-20</dateCreated>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>100901</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1982</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Linderholm, Helmer, 1916-1982</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">I de rödas krig / Helmer Linderholm</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>H,U</callNumber>
<item>
<totalCharges>1</totalCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate>2016-01-01</intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2006-12-18</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>30580001728158</itemID>
<library>VALLA</library>
<location>ULITT</location>
<type>HEMLAN</type>
<dateCreated>1996-06-20</dateCreated>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
</report>
```

First I want to filter - so it only contains items where dateLastUsed is older that five years. I think an If-clause would do it, but any suggestions are welcome!

Secondly I want a field that says - preferably in Years-months-days - how long time has passed since dateLastUsed.

This is my tentative stylesheet - and I have no clue on how to proceeed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                extension-element-prefixes="date">

<xsl:import href="date.xsl" />

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog[call/item[type='FLYTANDE' or type='HEMLAN']]">
    <xsl:sort select="call/item/library"/>
    <xsl:sort select="call/callNumber"/>
    <xsl:sort select="marc/marcEntry[@tag='100']"/>
    <xsl:sort select="marc/marcEntry[@tag='245']"/>
        <xsl:if test="call/item/intervalCheckouts = 0 and call/item/intervalRenewals = 0">
        <!--Here I want a second if.
        If today minus lastUsed is greater than five years
        -->
            <itemline>
                <yearOfPublication><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></yearOfPublication>
                <Author><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@tag='100']"/></Author>
                <Title><xsl:value-of select="substring(marc/marcEntry[@tag='245'],1,30)"/></Title>
                <callNumber><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="string(call/callNumber)"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text></callNumber>
                <library><xsl:value-of select="call/item/library"/></library>
                <itemID><xsl:value-of select="call/item/itemID"/></itemID>
                <type><xsl:value-of select="call/item/type"/></type>
                <location><xsl:value-of select="call/item/location"/></location>
                <totalCharges><xsl:value-of select="call/item/totalCharges"/></totalCharges>
                <itemCreated><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateCreated"/></itemCreated>
                <dateLastUsed><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateLastUsed"/></dateLastUsed>
                <today><xsl:value-of select="substring(//report/dateCreated,1,10)"/></today>
                <!--
                Here I want a duration: today minus lastUsed as Years - months - days
                -->
            </itemline>
        </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what processor are you using, have you checked that it supports exsl date? tried `<diff><xsl:value-of select="date:difference(substring(//report/dateCreated,1,10), call/item/dateLastUsed)"/></diff>` maybe some formatting using date:format-date around it?

Comment: **1.** Are you sure your processor supports the `date:difference()` function? -- **2.** Note that the function is supposed to return the difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds. There is no logical way to translate that to years, months and days. In fact, there is no agreed way to express any duration as years, months and days, because the number of days in a month varies.